# Difference between dictionary and OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I am trying to get a sorted dictionary. But the order of the items between `mydict` and `orddict` doesn't seem to change.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

orddict = OrderedDict(mydict)

print(mydict, orddict)

# print items in mydict:
print('mydict')
for k, v in mydict.items():
    print(k, v)

print('ordereddict')
# print items in ordered dictionary
for k, v in orddict.items():
    print(k, v)


# print the dictionary keys
# for key in mydict.keys():
#     print(key)


#  print the dictionary values
# for value in mydict.values():
#     print(value)
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As of [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html), a new improvement to the `dict` built-in is:

> the insertion-order preservation nature of dict objects has been declared to be an official part of the Python language spec.

This means there is no real need for `OrderedDict` anymore . They are almost the same.

---

### Some minor details to consider...

Here are some comparisons between Python 3.7+ `dict` and `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'b': 1, 'a': 2}
od = OrderedDict([('b', 1), ('a', 2)])

# they are equal with content and order
assert d == od
assert list(d.items()) == list(od.items())
assert repr(dict(od)) == repr(d)
```

Obviously, there is a difference between the string representation of the two object, with the `dict` object in more natural and compact form.

```
str(d)  # {'b': 1, 'a': 2}
str(od) # OrderedDict([('b', 1), ('a', 2)])
```

As for different methods between the two, this question can be answered with set theory:

```
d_set = set(dir(d))
od_set = set(dir(od))
od_set.difference(d_set)
# {'__dict__', '__reversed__', 'move_to_end'}  for Python 3.7
# {'__dict__', 'move_to_end'}  for Python 3.8+
```

This means `OrderedDict` has at most two features that `dict` does not have built-in, but work-arounds are shown here:

#### Workaround for [`__reversed__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__) / [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed)

No workaround is really needed for Python 3.8+, [which fixed this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue33462). `OrderedDict` can be "reversed", which simply reverses the keys (not the whole dictionary):

```
reversed(od)        # <odict_iterator at 0x7fc03f119888>
list(reversed(od))  # ['a', 'b']

# with Python 3.7:
reversed(d)                    # TypeError: 'dict' object is not reversible
list(reversed(list(d.keys()))) # ['a', 'b']

# with Python 3.8+:
reversed(d)        # <dict_reversekeyiterator at 0x16caf9d2a90>
list(reversed(d))  # ['a', 'b']
```

To properly reverse a whole dictionary using Python 3.7+:

```
dict(reversed(list(d.items())))  # {'a': 2, 'b': 1}
```

#### Workaround for `move_to_end`

`OrderedDict` has a `move_to_end` method, which is simple to implement:

```
od.move_to_end('b')  # now it is: OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('b', 1)])

d['b'] = d.pop('b')  # now it is: {'a': 2, 'b': 1}
```

Comment: This post should get more upvotes :D. Thanks Mike!

Answer (score 22):

An `OrderedDict` preserves the order elements were inserted:

```
>>> od = OrderedDict()
>>> od['c'] = 1
>>> od['b'] = 2
>>> od['a'] = 3
>>> od.items()
[('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
>>> d = {}
>>> d['c'] = 1
>>> d['b'] = 2
>>> d['a'] = 3
>>> d.items()
[('a', 3), ('c', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

So an `OrderedDict` does not *order* the elements for you, it *preserves*  the order you give it.

If you want to "sort" a dictionary, you probably want

```
>>> sorted(d.items())
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

Comment: And to convert a `dict` to an `OrderedDict` that (initially) has the keys in sorted order, you'd do: `od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))`.

Comment: Note that dicts are now insertion ordered by default.

Comment: Hmm, does this behavior change in higher python versions? It seems to maintain the order in Python 3.7.8 https://imgur.com/OJTKxkX

Comment: @RakshitKothari Yes it has! See the other answer - in Python 3.7+ `dict` now behaves the same as `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 9):

Starting with **CPython 3.6** and all other Python implementations starting with Python 3.7, the built-in **`dict` is ordered** - you get the items out in the order you inserted them. Which makes `dict` and `OrderedDict` effectively the same.

[The documentation for `OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) lists the remaining differences. The most important one is that

- **The equality operation for `OrderedDict` checks for matching order.**

Then there's a few minor practical differences:

- [`dict.popitem()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) takes no arguments, whereas [`OrderedDict.popitem(last=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem) accepts an optional `last=` argument that lets you pop the first item instead of the last item.
- `OrderedDict` has a [`move_to_end(key, last=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.move_to_end) method to efficiently reposition an element to the end or the beginning. With `dict`s you can move a key to the end by re-inserting it: `mydict['key'] = mydict.pop('key')`
- Until Python 3.8, you could do `reversed(OrderedDict())` but `reversed({})` would raise a `TypeError: 'dict' object is not reversible` error because they forgot to add a [`__reversed__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__) dunder method to `dict` when they made it ordered. This is now fixed.

And there are a few under-the-hood differences that might mean that you could get better performance for some specific usecase with `OrderedDict`:

- The regular `dict` was designed to be very good at mapping
  operations.  Tracking insertion order was secondary.
- The `OrderedDict` was designed to be good at reordering operations.
  Space efficiency, iteration speed, and the performance of update
  operations were secondary.
- Algorithmically, `OrderedDict` can handle frequent reordering
  operations better than `dict`.  This makes it suitable for tracking
  recent accesses (for example in an [LRU cache](https://medium.com/@krishankantsinghal/my-first-blog-on-medium-583159139237)).

See this [great talk from 2016 by Raymond Hettinger](https://youtu.be/p33CVV29OG8) for details on how Python dictionaries are implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to the answer by Brian, `OrderedDict` is really great. Here's why:

- You can use it as simple `dict` object because it supports equality testing with other `Mapping` objects like [collections.counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).
- `OrderedDict` preserves the insertion order as explained by Brian. In addition to that it has a method [popitem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem) which returns (key,value) pairs in LIFO order. So, you can also use it as a mapped 'stack'.

You not only get the full features of a `dict` but also, some cool tricks.

Comment: It does have a price for some aspects in speed and memory.

Answer (score 2):

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember the order that items were inserted. When iterating over an ordered dictionary, the items are returned in the order their keys were first added.

So it only sorts by order of adding into the dict

You can build an OrderedDict order by key as follow,

`orddict = OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items(), key = lambda t: t[0]))`

or simply as @ShadowRanger mentioned in comment

`orddict = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))`

If you want to order by value,

`orddict = OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items(), key = lambda t: t[1]))`

More information in [8.3.5.1. OrderedDict Examples and Recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes)