# Python - How do I return a dict key according to value in nested dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

I have a dictionary of dictionaries in Python.

I would like a way to go through each dict of dict, check the value of the 'val' key in each dictionary then return the initial dictionary key where 'val' == 0.

```
dict = {
    1: {'x': 'a', 'val': 1},
    2: {'x': 'b', 'val': 1},
    3: {'x': 'c', 'val': 0},
    4: {'x': 'c', 'val': 0}
}
```

I tried the following but that just return 3 and 4.

```
for itemid, iteminfo in data.items():
    for key in iteminfo:
        if iteminfo[key] == 0:
            print(str(itemid))
```

In the example above I would like 3 returned as it's the first instance where 'val' == 0.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Can you share the code you've written to solve your problem?

Comment: "it's the first instance where 'val' == 0": no, dictionaries aren't ordered.

Comment: You mean `orderedDict` because `dict` in general are not ordered

Comment: I'm new to coding and StackOverflow. I tried to come up with a solution by my self unsuccessfully. I tried several websites. The answer is probably obvious, I'm not seeing it as it's a dict of dict.

Comment: @DataPlankton post whatever you have tried. Unless we know where you are heading to we cannot help. Also this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305003/difference-between-dictionary-and-ordereddict-in-python/34305077

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Yes. My fault for not posting my attempt. I understand it makes it seem as if I didn't try. In the future will post my own attempts as well.

Comment: @mad_ Thanks for the advice about ordering the dict. I shall use the answer from the other post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the first occurrence of 'val' being paired with 0 (without any specific order, since dicts in python aren't ordered), you could use a break with the conditional statement inside your loop:

```
mydict = {
    1: {'x': 'a', 'val': 1},
    2: {'x': 'b', 'val': 1},
    3: {'x': 'c', 'val': 0},
    4: {'x': 'c', 'val': 0}
}

for key, value in mydict.items():
    if value['val'] == 0:
        print(key)
        break
```

If the order is important, you can go with an ordered dict

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it. Understood - will need to use an ordered dictionary.

Comment: I've posted it in the question above. My mistake.

Comment: NIce! This makes it easier for people to answer your question.