# Is the key order the same for OrderedDict and dict?

Tags: python

`dict` keeps insertion order since Python 3.6 (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)).

`OrderedDict` was developed just for this purpose (before Python 3.6).

Since Python 3.6, is the key order always the same for `dict` or `OrderedDict`?

I wonder whether I can do this in my code and have always the same behavior (except of equality, and some extended methods in `OrderedDict`) but more efficiently:

```
if sys.version_info[:2] >= (3, 6):
  OrderedDict = dict
else:
  from collections import OrderedDict
```

Or phrased differently, for Python >=3.6, is there any reason to use `OrderedDict`?

Comment: OrderedDict has methods that are not present in dict

Comment: Why you want to do that, when you can just do `from collections import OrderedDict` also in newer versions?

Comment: @Daweo: It would be much faster, right?

Comment: I think the practical question is why you would want to support Python 3.5 or earlier in the first place. [The oldest version still maintained is Python 3.6](https://www.python.org/downloads/), and even that is just security fixes.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305003/difference-between-dictionary-and-ordereddict

Comment: @Albert [``OrderedDict`` has a C implementation since Python 3.5](https://bugs.python.org/issue16991), so it should be competitive to ``dict`` for many operations.

Comment: @Albert then please test `OrderedDict` vs `dict` time consumptions for case which are most common in your usage

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Looking at the [current C implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/odictobject.c), it seems to be more complex that `dict` by using a linked list to explicitly store the order. Why does it need that when `dict` already keeps the order? But anyway, that makes it more complex, and thus also slower. Not sure by how much.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Regarding Python version: So, what would be the reason since Python 3.6 to use `OrderedDict` at all then? And my code snippet is just to make my question more explicit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both `OrderedDict` and `dict` are insertion-ordered¹ for iteration. There is practically no reason to use `OrderedDict` if iteration order is the only deciding point, especially if re-ordering is not needed.
Obviously, if *comparison* order is desired `OrderedDict` and `dict` are not interchangeable.

> Or phrased differently, for Python >=3.6, is there any reason to use `OrderedDict`?

These days `OrderedDict` is to `dict` what `deque` is to `list`, basically. `OrderedDict`/`deque` are based on linked lists² whereas `dict`/`list` are based on arrays. The former have better pop/move/FIFO semantics, since items can be removed from the start/middle without moving other items.

Since arrays are generally very cache friendly, the linked list advantage only comes into play for very large containers. Also, `OrderedDict` (unlike `deque`) does not have guarantees for its linked list semantics and its advantage may thus not be portable. `OrderedDict` should primarily be used if many pop/move/FIFO operations are needed and benchmarking can compare the performance of `dict` vs. `OrderedDict` in practice.

---

¹This applies to all currently supported implementations compliant with the Python language spec, i.e. CPython and PyPy since Python 3.6.

²`OrderedDict` in CPython still preserves O(1) key access. This is realised by *also* having a "regular" lookup table, using the linked list for order *between* items and the lookup table for *direct* item access. It's complicated.

Comment: The linked list in `OrderedDict` is just for storing the key order, not the mapping itself, which is just a normal `dict`. Although I wonder why `OrderedDict` actually needs to store the key order, if it is anyway the same.

Comment: @Albert The linked list order and item order (i.e. the ordering/storage of ``dict``) aren't the same when using ``move_to_end`` (and perhaps other methods). The linked list also allows *direct* access to the "first"/"last" item, whereas the ``dict`` item storage requires to scan for these to skip uninhabited slots.

Comment: Ah right. Although these are things I would never need for my use case (the only thing I need is insertion order of keys, nothing else). So it very much sounds like I should just use `dict` then. `dict` even has the comparison just as I want it.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that the different behavior of equality (`__eq__`) can be actually a major concern, why such code snippet is probably not good.

However, you could maybe still do this:

```
if sys.version_info[:2] >= (3, 6):
  OrderedDict = dict
else:
  from collections import OrderedDict as _OrderedDict

  class OrderedDict(_OrderedDict):
    __eq__ = dict.__eq__
    __ne__ = dict.__ne__
```

The difference is that with the original `collections.OrderedDict`, `{1:1,2:2}` is not the same as `{2:2,1:1}`, but for `dict` and my overwritten `OrderedDict` in this example, it is the same.

Comment: Might be worth expanding on this - some readers may not know the difference between equality of dicts vs. OrderedDicts.

Answer (score 1):

Some behaviour remains the same, but OrderedDict are reversible and dict are not:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = { "a" : 1, "c" : 2}

od = OrderedDict(d.items())

print(list(reversed(od)))
print(list(reversed(d)))
```

**Output**

```
['c', 'a']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/file", line 8, in <module>
    print(list(reversed(d)))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not reversible
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

> In addition to the usual mapping methods, ordered dictionaries also
> support reverse iteration using reversed().

Comment: Since Python 3.8, `reversed` does work on a regular `dict`. See [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: Can you be more specific on "some behaviour"? Which behavior exactly is different (except reversible in Python 3.6 and 3.7)? Or asked reversely, despite this, everything is the same?

Comment: When I was referring to some behaviour was the rest of it with exception of course of the methods present in OrderedDict that are not in dict. Out of curiosity, why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Using `dict` should be much faster than `OrderedDict`.