# Python - Accessing values from a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, ordereddictionary

Working on something for fun...completely new to programming. How do I access the values in the dictionary so I can either add the cost values or check if its a "Main" or "Side" item, etc.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

#Items on menu
item1 = OrderedDict(name = "Regular Pizza",
             cost = 20,
             item_type = "Main",
             size = "Regular")

item2 = OrderedDict(name = "Regular Salad",
             cost = 5,
             item_type = "Side",
             size = "Regular")
```

Comment: Why are you using `OrderedDict`? Have you done any research at all on using dictionaries in Python? The official tutorial, maybe?

Comment: `item1['name']` will get `name` for the variable `item1` here that would be `'Regular Pizza'.` You just use the key for the value you are looking for in quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @fam-woodpecker.

Comment: I was using OrderedDict so it can print in the order I wrote it, I tried using Pretty Printer. When I print it I want it in the order I wrote it and would like an empty line between each order combo(the combo is from the combinations of the multiple items I have in the code). Any tips will be appreciated @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 0):

Well, first things first.

I see that you are using `OrderedDict` from `collections` instead of just using `dict`. Don't do it, as you are new to Dictionary you should start from "vanilla dict" in my opinion.

OrderedDict as the name suggests is meant to preserve the order of the elements inside it.

But, after `Python 3.5` the order preservation feature was implemented to `dict`, read more in this answer - [Difference between dict and ordered dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58676384/12826764)

Also, as we access the dictionary values by their `key`, i don't think the order has much use here.

Now for your question on how to access the dictionary elements. Going from your example you have 2 items in the menu.

```
item1 = {
    'name' : 'Regular Pizza',
    'cost' : 20,
    'item_type' : 'Main',
    'size' : 'Regular'
}

item2 = {
    'name' : 'Regular Salad',
    'cost' : 5,
    'item_type' : 'Side',
    'size' : 'Regular'
}
```

Here i have created a dictionary with 2 items. Now

1. Check if the dish is main or not.

```
print ('The item is a ' + item1['item_type']+ ' dish')
```

2. Adding cost to items.

```
# increase item1 cost by 5
item1['cost'] += 5
```

Tip: Further you can put all the dishes inside a list and access them directly by the index values, with that you won't have to create multiple variables such as `item1, item2...`

The implemention would be like-

```
food = [
{   'name' : 'Regular Pizza',
    'cost' : 20,
    'item_type' : 'Main',
    'size' : 'Regular'}
,
{   'name' : 'Regular Salad',
    'cost' : 5,
    'item_type' : 'Side',
    'size' : 'Regular'}
]
```

Now to access the elements-

```
print ('The item is a ' + food[0]['item_type']+ ' dish')
```

```
food[0]['cost'] += 5
```

Comment: Thank You for the very helpful reply @anantdark Im doing possible combinations of all food items with a few conditions will I be able to find all combinations with dishes in 1 list. I will also be adding the cost of each item for total order cost(combination of dishes)

Comment: Glad i could help. Yes, you can make combinations and add the costs easily within the nested list. If you need further help, comment your github repo link and we can collaborate there. Also, mark this answer as correct if you have recieved your answer.